# Plot using Django,Rest Api and Plotly

Tags: html, css, django, rest, plotly-python

I am trying to plot using Rest API in Django with the help of plotly but I am not able to plot.i am using offline.plot then it's redirect to offline page but i am trying to this on my Django index page but it's not working

```
for repo_info in repositories:
    repo_names.append(repo_info['MeterReading_DateTime'])
    repo_stars.append(repo_info['ACT_IMP_TOT'])

data_plots = [{'type' : 'bar', 'x':repo_names , 'y': repo_stars}]
layout = {'title': 'MDM Data','xaxis': {'title': 'Date and time'},'yaxis': {'title': 'Total Import'}}
fig = {'data': data_plots, 'layout': layout}
 #offline.plot(fig, filename='Most_Popular_JavaScript_Repos.html')
return render(request, "index.html", context={'fig': fig})
```

Comment: what's the error / issue?

Comment: when i am using offline.plot then it's redirect to offline page but i am trying to this on my Django index page but it's not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.